# Are resources finite?

Tags: prey

Now that the duplication glitch has been patched, I'm becoming very cautious about what resources I use, and I was wondering:

Are resources finite? Is there a set amount of resources that it's possible to obtain throughout the entire game, or are there ways to farm resources indefinitely?

The only way I know of that seems to continually supply resources is saving people, but:

1. I haven't found out if they give forever
2. The rewards seem to be small in the long run.

Comment: One thing I can suggest is to unlock the 30% extra salvage from recycling ASAP and hold off recycling anything until you have it.

Comment: @Vyndicu It was the first skill I got. The surgical skill was second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources, that can be found on station, are finite, since locations, loot, and objects do not respawn. Yet, enemies are fairly often respawned, and may provide resources in form of generated loot and typhon organs. Organs, which require autopsy to get, give all categories of resources.

So, technically, if you are good enough to dispatch enemies without spending resources (e.g. typhon abilities build, and infinite psy tactics), you can roam through station locations, kill enemies, and farm resources as much as you want.

Comment: Yet, I've never experienced lack of resources to the end of my Nightmare run. I've ended up with 100+ of each resource. So, there are plenty of those to care too much

Comment: There's a rumor that enemies only respawn after advancing the story. This is wrong right? Because I'm pretty sure I keep going back to the machine shop area without advancing the story at all and there will always be 2+ phantoms and the purple phantom

Comment: @pete, enemies respawn all the time. Without advancing the story, it's just one Phantom and/or a couple of Mimics. They also only respawn in large, open areas (as opposed to tight corridors). Some areas are more likely to spawn enemies, like the Psychotronics Lobby, which always seems to spawn some, while the Talos I Lobby and even the Exterior spawn very rarely. Advancing the story also spawns enemies, though in much larger quantities and without limit on place or type. The only exception is the Nightmare, which only spawns at random and with the same probability everywhere large enough.